# Visual Composer - Define Editable Area

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I've got the following code in a Wordpress template

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Template Name: Service Details
 *
 */

header();
the_post();
?>
<main role="main">

    <?php banner(array(
        'colour'  => '#C4C332'
    )); ?>

    <div class="uk-block vc-area">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        partial('client-stories-grid');
    ?>

    <?php
        partial('lets-get-started');
    ?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And we've got Visual Composer installed - However when we're editing the page via visual composer - When clicking insert row etc - nothing happens.

We'd like to be able to define the container with the class `vc-area` to be where visual composer adds all its content.

This is the first time using VC so finding the terminology within their docs a bit tricky to figure this out.

how would I go about doing the above?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with their support it seems that wherever you are outputting `the_content()` during the loop should display the editor.

So the above code was working - but seemed there was strange bugs that after about 1 hour of not doing anything and going to lunch, it started to work.